# Onesignal node js Incorrect player_id format in include_player_ids

Tags: node.js, onesignal, android-push-notification

**When I am trying to send a push notification to the list of Android devices getting below error and notification not delivered to any device.**

```
 Error: [
   'Incorrect player_id format in include_player_ids (not a valid UUID): 1234567890'
 ]
```

**Devices array**

```
 device [
   '2e52e176-0764-47e4-944f-b211c12e9407',
   '1234567890',
   'e3bf4c0b-dd7e-486c-a4b9-838ea66c3233'
 ]
```

My question is

How I can handle the wrong device id (1234567890)?

Because of the wrong device id push notification not delivered to any device.